# Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route` while using route in react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, reactive-programming

this is the error that i get: 
Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`.

here is my index.js

```
var React= require('react');
var ReactDOM= require('react-dom');
var routes=require('./config/routes')

ReactDOM.render(
    routes,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

here is my routes.js

```
var React= require('react');
var ReactRouter= require('react-router');


var Router=ReactRouter.Router;
var Route=ReactRouter.Route; 
var IndexRoute=ReactRouter.IndexRoute;

var Main=require ('../components/Main');
var Home=require ('../components/Home');

var routes=(

    <Router>
        <Route path='/'component={Main}>
            <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
            </Route>
    </Router>

);

module.exports = routes;
```

My main.js

```
var React= require('react');


var Main= React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div>Hello from main
            {this.props.children}
            </div>


        )
    }
});

module.exports = Main;
```

and home.js

```
var React= require('react');


var Home=React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div>Hello from home</div>

        )
    }
});

module.exports = Home;
```

Comment: There is syntax error in `routes.js`: `var routes=(....)`, should be `var routes={....}`

Comment: shouldn't  main.js and home.js be **main.jsx** and **home.jsx** ???

Comment: routes worked fine, it was just a case sensitive issue that i wasn't aware of.

Comment: @Ursus: no `var routes=(....)` is good, it is like `var routes=....`. `( )` are usless anyways. But using  `{ }` would be wrong

Comment: @Kishore Barik: using `js` is as good as `jsx`. It depends how your bundler (webpack, ...) tracks your files

Answer (score 1):

You write `../components/Main`. try `../components/main`. I think it is case sensitive. Same thing for `Home`